# Does jQuery attr allow for non standards?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, attr

I am already using id and title but i need to parse through 2 more bits...

```
$(this).attr("title"); $(this).attr("id");
```

Will `$(this).attr("custom1");` work ??

Comment: You could try and tell us :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, and BTW you can set multiple attributes at once:

```
$('.myselector').attr({
src: 'thefile.gif',
width: 200,
height: 300 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and you can use it for all of the `data-attributes` in HTML5. Which is the preferrable way to add extra attributes.

Additionally, all `data-*` attributes are automatically added to jQuery's [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) object for easy access

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to associate (by name) some data with a DOM element, you're better off using the ".data()" method:

```
$(this).data('custom1', someValue);
```

The ".data()" API makes HTML5-style "data-foo" attributes coded into the HTML accessible:

```
var foo = $(this).data('foo'); // gets the "data-foo" attribute value from element
```

Comment: This is the cleaner solution in all points. So you're not polite your html markup with invalid attributes. Maybe you check out the api here too: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: @asrijaal: `.data` is not cleaner "in all points". There's a lack of symmetry between reading and writing with `.data`: `.data('custom', 'foo')` does not put `data-custom="foo"` into the DOM. `.attr` does not have this problem. Anything [primitive] you write to it will be accessible in the DOM.

Comment: @Roatin Marth yes that's true, but with consistent use of ".data()" I don't see why it matters. Attaching JavaScript objects directly to DOM elements is risky for memory use reasons, as (in IE primarily) JavaScript appendages to DOM elements can't be garbage-collected by the DOM collector.

Comment: I included "[primitive]" in my comment intentionally :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works, but it's not a good idea.

Better use [.data('foo', 'bar');](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) if you want to store some data on an element.

Comment: Why is it not a good idea? Does .data() work on pages with pre-html5 doctypes and in IE8? .attr() seems to work fine for me, though im curious as to why .data is the better choice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and the best thing you can do is just test it.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  alert( "custom1 = " + $("#myField").attr("custom1") );
});
</script>

<div id="myField" custom1="My Custom Field"></div>
```

Now, you are breaking markup, so I would suggest storing your info in ALT tags or NAME tags to prevent that ().