# Custom input attributes selectable via JQuery?

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, custom-attributes

Is it possible first to use custom attributes, secondly use Jquery to select it and thirdly that it is compatible with most browsers. IE7 and IE6 being the big issue I would imagine.

So

`<input id="checkit" type="checkbox" value="12" alt="1286" title="Press this" reference="1469" level="red"/>`

JQuery

```
var test = $('#checkit').attr('reference')
```

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Comment: You can use the HTML5 `data` attributes: `<input ... data-level="red">`, the others will probably work too but aren't valid HTML.

Comment: As far as I know it works on all browsers, even IE6.

Comment: If I am not mistaken IE6 and IE7 certainly will not run HTML 5

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does jQuery attr allow for non standards ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223414/does-jquery-attr-allow-for-non-standards). Fresh and hot, just 5 hours old :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/RkSNg/1/

Comment: Works is Firefox Safari and IE7. Would it be a problem in IE6?

Comment: @Robin I just tested in IE6 and it worked. But like the others said, it's not valid HTML.

Comment: @Robin Knight: why would you wanna do this if there is an extra method to accomplish what you are trying to do? just prepend "data-" to your attributes and you are good to go. look at the link i posted.

Answer (score 3):

use the .data() method:

http://api.jquery.com/data/

it's in the core, so it is crossbrowser.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any problem in doing that, only the document wouldn't validate(if you won't specify your custom scheme :) )

A better way would be, for example, store data in a variable in a JSON format and refecrence it by elements id.